# R - Control variables missing for one group in logit: How to interpret coefficient?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, logit

I have data on passes and points in US basketball games.

I want to know whether the key variable is different for the intra-team pass (1) or a steal/rebound (0) group. I also have three control variables and one fixed effects (not added to the example data below).

**Problem:** My control variables are only measured for intra-team pass (1) group observations. Not for the steal/rebounds (0) group observations.

The observations are structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame(pass = c(0,1,0,1,1,0),
               key_variable= c(9,2,5,7,1,3),
               control1= c(NA,1,NA,2,2,NA),
               control2= c(NA,15,NA,14,14,NA),
               control3= c(NA, 7, NA, 3, 2, NA))
> df
  pass key_variable control1 control2 control3
1    0            9       NA       NA       NA
2    1            2        1       15        7
3    0            5       NA       NA       NA
4    1            7        2       14        3
5    1            1        2       14        2
6    0            3       NA       NA       NA
```

The real data consists of 8 million observations.

When I run a (conditional) logit with the `survival` or `bife` package, the control variables are insignificant.

```
model1 <- bife(pass ~ key_variable + control1 + control2 + control3 | some_fixed_effect, 
                      data=df, bias_corr="ana")
```

**Questions:**

- Are the control variables insignificant because they miss
  observations for the steal/rebound observations?
- Do the control variables still have an effect on the relation between the key variable and the dependent variable in the model?

  - Are there other statistical approaches to examine the differences between pass and non-pass observations using these data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do with the conditional logit model. You write that you want to "know whether there are differences between points that are scored as a consequence of an intra-team pass (1) or a steal/rebound (0)". Assuming that the key variable is the "points scored", one way to analyze this is to do a logistic regression using pass/steal/rebound as the dependent variable and the key variable as an independent variable. Another way is to do a Poisson regression using the key variable as the dependent variable and pass/steal/rebound as an independent variable. This seems preferable to me provided that the key variable (again, assuming that this represents points scored) conditioned on pass/steal/rebound approximately follows a Poisson distribution.

Now what about the control variables? If you do a logistic regression you have to omit them because they don't tell you anything about the probability of the dependent variable being a pass or a steal/rebound since they are only recorded in for the last category. But if you do a poisson regression, you can use them even if all values for passes are missing. The trick is to create interaction terms between the pass category and the control variables that will be equal to the control variables for those in the pass category and 0 for the other category:

```
passXcontrol1 <- ifelse(df$pass==0, 0, df$control1)
passXcontrol2 <- ifelse(df$pass==0, 0, df$control2)
passXcontrol3 <- ifelse(df$pass==0, 0, df$control3)
```

And now, you can do the poisson regression:

```
model <- glm(key_variable ~ pass + passXcontrol1 + passXcontrol2 + passXcontrol3, family=poisson, data=df)
```

The estimated coefficients for the interaction terms will tell you the effect of the control variables on the key variable in steals/rebounds, and the effect of being a pass compared to steal/rebound will be estimated with the pass variable.